# How to clip path from image and set brightness to the unclipped path

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using clip-path for an image to look like a QR code scanner and whatever I try I'm unable to achieve it. I want to do this.

[image]

I want to clip path a square from an image. and make a little less bright the unclipped path of image.

when I set clip path I'm getting this. is there any way of doing this the right way. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You want a mask not a clip path I suspect.

Comment: And use `opacity` to have same effect as in 1st image

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? We have tried one solution hope it will work for you.

Take the image div as a background and then set it to position relative, with respect to it take a pseudo-element `before` of the parent div and set its position with respect to parent div(i.e. is image div) and apply the box-shadow to it, and set the parent div to overflow hidden.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/8pfhbu1L/